# Transparent inline matplotlibs in IPython

Tags: matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'd like the background of my matplotlib plots to be transparent in my IPython notebook. This may sound silly because the notebook itself defaults to a white background but:

1) I use a solarized background and

2) more importantly, I want them to be transparent for when I embed the notebook directly into my blog via `nbconvert`.

It's easy enough to use something like `savefig('file', transparent=True)` , but I'm not saving the figures, I am displaying them inline (by calling IPython with `ipython notebook --matplotlib inline`.

I've been playing around with the IPython notebook configuration file, especially with `c.InlineBackend.rc`. For example, I upgraded to the dev version of matplotlib to get access to its new `savefig.transparent` rcParam, and tried configuring that with `c.InlineBackend.rc = {'savefig.transparent': True}`, but as expected it only affects plots saved with `savefig`.

Note that I am using the recent IPython 2.0 release. This must be possible *somehow*, right? Any light that you can shed would be appreciated.

Comment: the figures are displayed via pngs which are embedded directly in the html. You _are_ saving the figures, ipython is just hiding it from you.  You probably have to dig into the ipython code to find where the do the save and add the ability to pass parameters through.

Comment: I feel that your second approach should work (setting the ipython rc parameter).

Comment: @tillsten, my suspicion is that this means IPython is not calling `savefig` directly when it uses matplotlib inline. Maybe it is using some lower level function? I'll poke around and try to find out, but hopefully someone more knowledgable about these things knows off the top of their head.

Comment: I posted an issue on the ipython github page, maybe they know more. I tried every i way i could think of (figure constructor, rcparmas, ipython config) without being able to set to figure facecolor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to follow up, the issue opened on Github by tillsten has been patched so something like this:

```
rcParams['figure.facecolor'] = (0,0,0,0)
```

should work now after you update IPython. Three cheers for open source.

Answer (score 0):

The inline plots are html objects (`<img>`) with class `ui-resizable`. So you can change their default behavior by customizing the CSS for your notebooks:

1. locate your settings for notebooks: in a terminal, type

   ```
   ipython locate
   ```
2. in the indicated directory, go to subdir `profile_default\static\custom` (or any profile you want to use instead)
3. edit or create a CSS file named `custom.css`
4. put this in it:

   ```
   img.ui-resizable
   {
   opacity:0.4;
   }
   ```

Close your notebooks, kill IPython and restart it (so that it recreates the served files).

It should work with exported notebooks, as long as you export them as html and you change the css there too.

It's not exactly what you want, but it does the job.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't at all what I want. This makes the whole image transparent, including the content, and does nothing to change the white background.

Comment: Sure, I now understand that you only want the _background_ to be (fully) transparent.